# How can I display likes/dislikes MySQL, NodeJS

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, database

```
    CREATE TABLE post_likes (
       post_id                INT NOT NULL, 
       user_id                INT NOT NULL, 
       likes                  BOOLEAN NOT NULL,         
       FOREIGN KEY            (post_id) REFERENCES posts(id),
       FOREIGN KEY            (user_id) REFERENCES users(id),
       PRIMARY KEY            (user_id, post_id) 
    )


    +-------+---------+---------+
    | likes | post_id | user_id |
    +-------+---------+---------+
    |     1 |       1 |       1 |
    |     1 |       1 |       2 |
    |     0 |       2 |       1 |
    |     0 |       2 |       2 |
    +-------+---------+---------+
```

I am using NodeJS and EJS as templating language. Right now I am passing the table post_likes to my EJS. And trying to do a for loop. Basically in the table 1=true or like and 0=false or dislike. So I have a counter and if it is a like I do counter++ else counter--. But it looks bad. Also its not working for some reason What is a better way to do this.

What I tried - I excluded the other parts of the code that was not needed. I removed the ejs closing brackets and open to make it more readable.

```
<% var counter = 0 %>

for(var i = posts.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
     if(posts[i].post_likes.length > 0) { 
        for(var j = 0; j < posts[i].post_likes.length; j++) { 
             if(posts[i].post_likes[j].likes == true) { 
                 counter = counter + 1 %>
             } 
             else if(posts[i].post_likes[j].likes == false) { 
                 counter = counter - 1 
             } 
         } 
     } 
}

<h1><%= counter %></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this to get the total of liked and unliked posts.

```
var posts = [{
    post_likes: [{
        likes: true
    }]
}, {
    post_likes: [{
        likes: true
    }]
}, {
    post_likes: [{
        likes: false
    }]
}, {
    post_likes: [{
        likes: true
    }]
}];

var likedPosts = 0;
var unlikedPosts = 0;

posts.forEach(function(post) {
    likedPosts += post.post_likes.filter(function(v) {
        return v.likes === true;
    }).length;

    unlikedPosts += post.post_likes.filter(function(v) {
        return v.likes === false;
    }).length;
});

console.log('Liked posts: ' + likedPosts);
console.log('Unliked posts: ' + unlikedPosts);
```